# Visual Studio Extension to modify the Go to All search results?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vssdk

Would it be possible to create an extensions that modifies what appears in the Go to All search results of Visual Studio 2017? I'd like to build an extension that lets the user (within Tools -> Options...) define any number of glob patterns for paths that should be excluded from this search. If it's possible could anyone point me in the right direction on what APIs to use?

The extension could either use the globs to instruct VS to filter what locations are searched, or it could receive the results and remove the unwanted ones before they are displayed - depending on what APIs are available.

This would for example be useful when you're working with a typescript project that compiles into js into some other folder, but you only want to search your ts files, or even more if you're working with some framework where html files are copied from the location where you code them to the location(s) where they need to be when running the app(s).

[image]